# Is there a way to redirect requests from a web server with static address to a game server with dynamic address?

Tags: hosting, server-administration

My server doesn't have a static ip so every time I boot the server, I have to tell my friends which is the ip.

Now I have a web server I'm renting out for websites and testing, with port 80 opened (plus probably a few others I guess), so I'm wondering if there is a way to create a subdomain for example http://game.domain.com that would redirect to my other server automatically by using .htaccess so I could just change it there and my friends would only have one address to remember.

I'm just concerned that the game traffic will constantly pass through my webserver, like a proxy and lag everyone. Am I correct?

Is there a way to do this with the game being redirected then finally use the end IP address, kind of like a permanent redirect once the connection has been established?

Comment: You might want to look into dynamic dns for your game server. The idea behind it being that every time you boot it and get a new IP that it will update a DNS record so that the server name will be consistent and correct within a few minutes of server boot. I've not used it myself but it is designed for exactly the kind of thing you want to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about server access and networking, not gaming.

Comment: I think [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) does networking.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I researched Dynamic DNS and was able to set an automatic service with their API to redirect a subdomain to my ever-changing IP. Thanks for the suggestion as well DJ Pirtu, I fixed my problem but I'll keep that in mind for next time :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, for people who might be looking into the gaming section to do this, it is possible. I did not use a web .htaccess redirect, but after a suggestion of @Chris, I checked out Dynamic DNS services.

I ended up finding dynu.com who offers free dynamic DNS service and the best part is that you don't have to install anything on your server!

They have an API so I rigged up a quick script to send a GET request including the server's IP to Dynu and it just updates automatically. If you wish to to the same, make sure to lower the TTL so it updates faster.

Comment: Downvote for the actual solution which fixed my problem... whoever troll did this, I'm sorry to say but you are very much useless to this community

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot.

What you are describing is exactly how a proxy server works.  A standard web server will not give you enough control to set this up.